# Prometheus rate query over a long period

Tags: prometheus

When using the `rate` function over a long period (e.g. `7d`) I am getting the error `"query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution"`.

My query is

```
histogram_quantile(0.90, rate(http_request_in_seconds_bucket[7d]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because Prometheus has [a limit of samples](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/cmd/prometheus/main.go#L255) it can process in memory.

I solved this with subqueries which was [added on Prometheus 2.7](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).
This allows you to separately query smaller time intervals and then aggregate them together.

For example, I changed my query to multiple 24 hours subqueries and then averaged it together

`histogram_quantile(0.90, avg_over_time(rate(http_request_in_seconds_bucket[24h])[7d:12h]))`

There are other solutions:

1. Increase the number of samples it can process by changing the flag `query.max-samples` (not recommended)
2. Use [Recording Rules](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/implementing-slos-using-prometheus.html) - recommended over subqueries as it reduces the load on prometheus servers, but takes more efforts to set up.